# Strongloop Process Manager: Error: password authentication for user "USER"

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I am trying to run a loopback app on a digital ocean Ubuntu instance.

After deploying the app to my instance while running the sl-pm command,  I get the following error:

It seems that some user somewhere is failing password authentication.  How to I locate the source of this problem?

```
pvijeh@places-api:~$ sl-pm
sl-pm(14743): StrongLoop PM v5.1.0 (API v6.1.0) on port `8701`
sl-pm(14743): Base folder `/home/pvijeh/.strong-pm`
sl-pm(14743): Applications on port `3000 + service ID`
Browse your REST API at http://127.0.0.1:8701/explorer
Run request for commit "1/default" on current (none)
Start Runner: commit 1/default
2015-12-29T22:27:15.316Z pid:14752 worker:0 INFO strong-agent v2.0.2 profiling app 'placesAPI' pid '14752'
2015-12-29T22:27:15.337Z pid:14752 worker:0 INFO strong-agent[14752] started profiling agent
2015-12-29T22:27:15.343Z pid:14752 worker:0 INFO supervisor starting (pid 14752)
2015-12-29T22:27:15.349Z pid:14752 worker:0 INFO strong-agent strong-agent using strong-cluster-control v2.2.1
2015-12-29T22:27:15.357Z pid:14752 worker:0 INFO supervisor reporting metrics to `internal:`
2015-12-29T22:27:15.384Z pid:14752 worker:0 INFO strong-agent not profiling, agent metrics requires a valid license.
2015-12-29T22:27:15.386Z pid:14752 worker:0 Please contact sales@strongloop.com for assistance.
2015-12-29T22:27:15.409Z pid:14752 worker:0 INFO supervisor size set to 2
2015-12-29T22:27:15.607Z pid:14752 worker:0 INFO supervisor started worker 1 (pid 14757)
2015-12-29T22:27:15.896Z pid:14752 worker:0 INFO supervisor started worker 2 (pid 14762)
2015-12-29T22:27:15.897Z pid:14752 worker:0 INFO supervisor resized to 2
2015-12-29T22:27:17.249Z pid:14757 worker:1 INFO strong-agent v2.0.2 profiling app 'placesAPI' pid '14757'
2015-12-29T22:27:17.249Z pid:14757 worker:1 INFO strong-agent[14757] started profiling agent
2015-12-29T22:27:17.635Z pid:14762 worker:2 INFO strong-agent v2.0.2 profiling app 'placesAPI' pid '14762'
2015-12-29T22:27:17.651Z pid:14762 worker:2 INFO strong-agent[14762] started profiling agent
2015-12-29T22:27:21.047Z pid:14757 worker:1 INFO strong-agent not profiling, agent metrics requires a valid license.
2015-12-29T22:27:21.048Z pid:14757 worker:1 Please contact sales@strongloop.com for assistance.
2015-12-29T22:27:21.098Z pid:14757 worker:1 Connection fails:  { [error: password authentication failed for user "pvijeh"]
2015-12-29T22:27:21.099Z pid:14757 worker:1   name: 'error',
2015-12-29T22:27:21.100Z pid:14757 worker:1   length: 95,
2015-12-29T22:27:21.100Z pid:14757 worker:1   severity: 'FATAL',
2015-12-29T22:27:21.101Z pid:14757 worker:1   code: '28P01',
2015-12-29T22:27:21.102Z pid:14757 worker:1   detail: undefined,
2015-12-29T22:27:21.103Z pid:14757 worker:1   hint: undefined,
2015-12-29T22:27:21.103Z pid:14757 worker:1   position: undefined,
2015-12-29T22:27:21.104Z pid:14757 worker:1   internalPosition: undefined,
2015-12-29T22:27:21.104Z pid:14757 worker:1   internalQuery: undefined,
2015-12-29T22:27:21.104Z pid:14757 worker:1   where: undefined,
2015-12-29T22:27:21.105Z pid:14757 worker:1   schema: undefined,
2015-12-29T22:27:21.106Z pid:14757 worker:1   table: undefined,
2015-12-29T22:27:21.106Z pid:14757 worker:1   column: undefined,
2015-12-29T22:27:21.109Z pid:14757 worker:1   dataType: undefined,
2015-12-29T22:27:21.110Z pid:14757 worker:1   constraint: undefined,
2015-12-29T22:27:21.110Z pid:14757 worker:1   file: 'auth.c',
2015-12-29T22:27:21.112Z pid:14757 worker:1   line: '304',
2015-12-29T22:27:21.112Z pid:14757 worker:1   routine: 'auth_failed' }
2015-12-29T22:27:21.113Z pid:14757 worker:1 It will be retried for the next request.
2015-12-29T22:27:21.114Z pid:14757 worker:1 events.js:142
2015-12-29T22:27:21.115Z pid:14757 worker:1       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2015-12-29T22:27:21.115Z pid:14757 worker:1       ^
2015-12-29T22:27:21.116Z pid:14757 worker:1 error: password authentication failed for user "pvijeh"
2015-12-29T22:27:21.116Z pid:14757 worker:1     at Connection.parseE (/home/pvijeh/.strong-pm/svc/1/work/aeb39b8ff6393282f657f3c1f703760c207e265c.1451426442510/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:539:11)
2015-12-29T22:27:21.118Z pid:14757 worker:1     at Connection.parseMessage (/home/pvijeh/.strong-pm/svc/1/work/aeb39b8ff6393282f657f3c1f703760c207e265c.1451426442510/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:366:17)
2015-12-29T22:27:21.123Z pid:14757 worker:1     at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/pvijeh/.strong-pm/svc/1/work/aeb39b8ff6393282f657f3c1f703760c207e265c.1451426442510/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:105:22)
2015-12-29T22:27:21.123Z pid:14757 worker:1     at emitOne (events.js:78:13)
2015-12-29T22:27:21.124Z pid:14757 worker:1     at Socket.emit (events.js:170:7)
2015-12-29T22:27:21.124Z pid:14757 worker:1     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:147:16)
2015-12-29T22:27:21.127Z pid:14757 worker:1     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:111:10)
2015-12-29T22:27:21.127Z pid:14757 worker:1     at TCP.onread (net.js:524:20)
2015-12-29T22:27:21.154Z pid:14752 worker:0 ERROR supervisor worker id 1 (pid 14757) accidental exit with 1
2015-12-29T22:27:23.054Z pid:14762 worker:2 INFO strong-agent not profiling, agent metrics requires a valid license.
2015-12-29T22:27:23.054Z pid:14762 worker:2 Please contact sales@strongloop.com for assistance.
2015-12-29T22:27:23.083Z pid:14762 worker:2 Web server listening at: http://0.0.0.0:3001
2015-12-29T22:27:23.085Z pid:14762 worker:2 Browse your REST API at http://0.0.0.0:3001/explorer
sl-pm: Service "1" listening on 0.0.0.0:3001
2015-12-29T22:27:23.206Z pid:14762 worker:2 Connection fails:  { [error: password authentication failed for user "pvijeh"]
2015-12-29T22:27:23.207Z pid:14762 worker:2   name: 'error',
2015-12-29T22:27:23.207Z pid:14762 worker:2   length: 95,
2015-12-29T22:27:23.208Z pid:14762 worker:2   severity: 'FATAL',
2015-12-29T22:27:23.209Z pid:14762 worker:2   code: '28P01',
2015-12-29T22:27:23.212Z pid:14762 worker:2   detail: undefined,
2015-12-29T22:27:23.212Z pid:14762 worker:2   hint: undefined,
2015-12-29T22:27:23.213Z pid:14762 worker:2   position: undefined,
2015-12-29T22:27:23.216Z pid:14762 worker:2   internalPosition: undefined,
2015-12-29T22:27:23.216Z pid:14762 worker:2   internalQuery: undefined,
2015-12-29T22:27:23.217Z pid:14762 worker:2   where: undefined,
2015-12-29T22:27:23.217Z pid:14762 worker:2   schema: undefined,
2015-12-29T22:27:23.224Z pid:14762 worker:2   table: undefined,
2015-12-29T22:27:23.226Z pid:14762 worker:2   column: undefined,
2015-12-29T22:27:23.226Z pid:14762 worker:2   dataType: undefined,
2015-12-29T22:27:23.226Z pid:14762 worker:2   constraint: undefined,
2015-12-29T22:27:23.227Z pid:14762 worker:2   file: 'auth.c',
2015-12-29T22:27:23.227Z pid:14762 worker:2   line: '304',
2015-12-29T22:27:23.227Z pid:14762 worker:2   routine: 'auth_failed' }
2015-12-29T22:27:23.228Z pid:14762 worker:2 It will be retried for the next request.
2015-12-29T22:27:23.228Z pid:14762 worker:2 events.js:142
2015-12-29T22:27:23.235Z pid:14762 worker:2       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2015-12-29T22:27:23.236Z pid:14762 worker:2       ^
2015-12-29T22:27:23.236Z pid:14762 worker:2 error: password authentication failed for user "pvijeh"
2015-12-29T22:27:23.236Z pid:14762 worker:2     at Connection.parseE (/home/pvijeh/.strong-pm/svc/1/work/aeb39b8ff6393282f657f3c1f703760c207e265c.1451426442510/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:539:11)
2015-12-29T22:27:23.236Z pid:14762 worker:2     at Connection.parseMessage (/home/pvijeh/.strong-pm/svc/1/work/aeb39b8ff6393282f657f3c1f703760c207e265c.1451426442510/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:366:17)
2015-12-29T22:27:23.237Z pid:14762 worker:2     at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/pvijeh/.strong-pm/svc/1/work/aeb39b8ff6393282f657f3c1f703760c207e265c.1451426442510/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:105:22)
2015-12-29T22:27:23.238Z pid:14762 worker:2     at emitOne (events.js:78:13)
2015-12-29T22:27:23.239Z pid:14762 worker:2     at Socket.emit (events.js:170:7)
2015-12-29T22:27:23.240Z pid:14762 worker:2     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:147:16)
2015-12-29T22:27:23.240Z pid:14762 worker:2     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:111:10)
2015-12-29T22:27:23.240Z pid:14762 worker:2     at TCP.onread (net.js:524:20)
2015-12-29T22:27:23.253Z pid:14752 worker:0 ERROR supervisor worker id 2 (pid 14762) accidental exit with 1
2015-12-29T22:27:23.493Z pid:14752 worker:0 INFO supervisor started worker 3 (pid 14778)
2015-12-29T22:27:24.613Z pid:14778 worker:3 INFO strong-agent v2.0.2 profiling app 'placesAPI' pid '14778'
2015-12-29T22:27:24.625Z pid:14778 worker:3 INFO strong-agent[14778] started profiling agent
2015-12-29T22:27:25.782Z pid:14752 worker:0 INFO supervisor started worker 4 (pid 14783)
2015-12-29T22:27:25.783Z pid:14752 worker:0 INFO supervisor resized to 2
2015-12-29T22:27:27.298Z pid:14783 worker:4 INFO strong-agent v2.0.2 profiling app 'placesAPI' pid '14783'
2015-12-29T22:27:27.323Z pid:14783 worker:4 INFO strong-agent[14783] started profiling agent
```

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the trace output here:

```
Connection.parseE (/home/pvijeh/.strong-pm/svc/1/work/...node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:539:11)
                                                                      ^^
```

You can see that the exception occurred inside the `pg` library, which is the PostgreSQL library for node. Check that your app is using the correct database password and/or you've set the proper environment variables for the service ID.